# kubernetes helm: How to set env variable of child chart in parent chart

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

We are using helm to deploy many charts, but for simplicity let's say it is two charts. A parent chart and a child chart:

```
helm/parent 
helm/child
```

The parent chart has a `helm/parent/requirements.yaml` file which specifies:

```
dependencies:
  - name: child
    repository: file://../child
    version: 0.1.0
```

The child chart requires a bunch of environment variables on startup for configuration, for example in `helm/child/templates/deployment.yaml`

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        env:
        - name: A_URL
          value: http://localhost:8080
```

What's the best way to override the child's environment variable from the parent chart, so that I can run the parent using below command and set the `A_URL` env variable for this instance to e.g. `https://www.mywebsite.com`?

```
helm install parent --name parent-release --namespace sample-namespace
```

I tried adding the variable to the parent's `helm/parent/values.yaml` file, but to no avail

```
global:
  repository: my_repo
  tag: 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
child:
  env:
    - name: A_URL
      value: https://www.mywebsite.com
```

Is the syntax of the parent's value.yaml correct? Is there a different approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the child chart you have to explicitly reference a value from the configuration.  (Having made this change you probably need to run `helm dependency update` from the parent chart directory.)

```yaml
# child/templates/deployment.yaml, in the pod spec
env:
- name: A_URL
  value: {{ .Values.aUrl | quote }}
```

You can give it a default value for the child chart.

```yaml
# child/values.yaml
aUrl: "http://localhost:8080"
```

Then in the parent chart's values file, you can provide an override value for that.

```yaml
# parent/values.yaml
child:
  aUrl: "http://elsewhere"
```

You can't use Helm to override or inject arbitrary YAML, except to the extent the templates allow for it.

Comment: please add one example. I am doing same but can't achieve as expected. Also if possible please focuse on access variable from helm subcharts to parent subchart.

Answer (score 1):

Unless the value is set up using the templating system, there is no way to directly modify it in Helm 2.

Comment: There are templates, in specific the A_URL variable is defined in the child's helm/child/templates/child.yaml template file. How would I best use the templating system to make the variable overridable?

Comment: In addition, please take a look for [Overriding Values of a Child Chart, Global Chart and values and Sharing Templates with Subcharts](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/master/docs/chart_template_guide/subcharts_and_globals.md)